# How to create and save log files in apex?

Tags: apex, managed-package, debugging

I'am creating a managed package and I know that the logs for the managed package in not visible in the debug log.
So, I wanted to create the log files for the process running at the backend for the functionality running in my Package and save the files somewhere in the Salesforce database.
How can we create these files in apex and save them so that in case we need to see the logs for the package we can view them using these log files.

Comment: You can use a custom object to track all the desired functionality. Also maybe use a custom setting to switch logging.

Comment: @RahulSharma, how to create and save the logs in custom object or custom setting.

Comment: In case you are unaware, the logs for the managed package are visible in the debug log, when you [log into the subscriber's org through your License Management App](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/lma_logging_in_to_sub_org.htm).